# After upgrading to Magento 1.9.3 none of my product thumbnails are showing in the backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, thumbnail

After upgrading to Magento 1.9.3 none of my product thumbnails are showing in the backend.

My old and new images aren't showing, folder permissions are set to 777.

All was fine in the previous version of magento. Shall I roll back? If so what's the best way to roll back now my store has taken orders in the new version?

Comment: please note, 1.9.3 contain certain major issues on which magento is currently working on. It wuld be better to upgrade till version 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

This is just a browser cache issue. You need to clear your browser cache from the beginning of time and it will resolved the problem. :D